# Problema para hacer web scrapping sobre una página que cambias sus estructuras y sus clases constantemente

Tags: java, web-scrapping, jsoup

estoy intentando crear un script con el que obtener los precios y productos de los mcdonald's que hay en ubereats. Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de hacer el parse buscando mediante etiquetas y clases ya que he detectado que el código cambia con cada url diferente que introduzco, No se como hacer

```
String url = ;

try {
   
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

  
    Element specificDiv = document.selectFirst("div.ch.d2.cj.d3");

  
    if (specificDiv != null) {

        Element spanTag = specificDiv.selectFirst("span[data-testid=rich-text].f3.ei.f4.ch.d2.cj.d3.b1");

        
        if (spanTag != null) {
            System.out.println("Etiqueta span dentro del div ch d2 cj d3:");
            System.out.println(spanTag.outerHtml());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encontró la etiqueta span dentro del div ch d2 cj d3.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No se encontró el div ch d2 cj d3.");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Cuando digo que cambia me refiero a que las clase cambian el nombre cada vez que lo inspecciono. Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="clase ejemplo 1"></div>
```

pasa a ser

```
<div class="clase ejemplo 20"> </div>
```

Cada vez que abro inspecciono el codigo fuente. Si tengo el código fuente abierto en Chrome y en Opera, aunque sea el mismo código las clases  diferentes.

Comment: El código cambia como?. Nos regalas un ejemplo para entender el problema?, tambien parte de tu script nos vendría bien para ayudarte.

Comment: Perdonad si me explico mal ya que es la primera vez que posteo y no tengo tampoco mucho conocimiento.

Comment: Cuando digo que cambia me refiero a que las clase cambian el nombre cada vez que lo inspecciono. Por ejemplo: <div class="clase ejemplo 1"></div> pasa a ser <div class="clase ejemplo 20"> </div>cada vez que abro inspecciono el codigo fuente. Si tengo el codigo fuente abierto en chrome y en opera aunque sea el mismo codigo las clases  difsonerentes

Comment: Eso es estraño, pero puede ser que es una medida de prevención para que alguien como nosotros creemos un script que haga eso...

Comment: Lo que describes es relativamente normal con CSS-en-JS, las clases se generan al vuelo dependiendo del contenido que haya en la pagina y entonces no tienen los mismos nombres cada vez que se visita la página.